# 4 hour browse watch, cert performance and multi app test

Tags: youtube, cobalt

Recently observing that 4 hour browse to watch, multi app performance and cert performance tests are only navigating and not playing any content. This was working on same code till last week. We tried few things and find out that if brand name is not passed then most of the time test behaves as expected. Has anything changed on YouTube backend?

Answer (score 0):

For the questions about YouTube, please reach out to your Technical Account Manager at YouTube.